# Is it possible to intercept http calls to images and change them with javascript?

Tags: javascript, function

I want to add some arguments to all images in a website, but these are dynamic.
Unfortunately the (only) way I have to do this would be by intercepting the image before loading. Javascript would be the only way to go here since I can change the header.
Any third party libraries like jquery are not an option.

Something like:
**http://www.example.com/acme.jpg**

Would be captured and transformed into

**http://www.example.com/acme.jpg?v=120**

The way I see it javacript would have to be, inline, in the header of the page, before the images start to load. I don't need to change the html itself, only intercept when the browser calls the image and tweak it a bit as ilustrated.

Is this possible?

Comment: Think this needs clarification.  Is it your page or are you loading remote pages?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change src of image before request has been sent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14415027/change-src-of-image-before-request-has-been-sent)

Comment: @DavidSherret It's similar but not the same. I can't change anything in the already existing html. Maybe only add some javascript on top. None of the solutions is usefull

Comment: @nsn see the first sentence in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14415059/188246) specifically.

Comment: @DavidSherret I would assume that if the js is in an external file no if its in-line. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

You could try this jquery solution :

```
$(function() {
  $( "img" ).load(function() { // select your images here
      var src = $( this ).attr("src");
      $(this).attr("src", src + "?v=120" ); // set the new url here
  });
}
```

Comment: That requires jquery. I dont want to rely on that. Thank you.

Comment: It's so easier with JQuery. If you wan't a pure js solution, you can just rewrite the function in my answer. The logic is the same.

Comment: The solution is simple, true, but I think by the time it's executed images already started to load.

Comment: That's probably true, but once the `src` has been changed, the new images should start to load. I think you won't be able to notice it, and should anyway give it a try.